# Comparing SKNode's userData gives an error

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

An SKNode can have userData to store arbitrary data.

I set the property "isEvil" on two SKNodes. Then I want to check if both nodes are evil.

```
var hero = SKNode()
hero.userData = ["isEvil": false]

var enemy = SKNode()
enemy.userData = ["isEvil": true]

if hero.userData!["isEvil"] == enemy.userData!["isEvil"] {
  println("the here and the enemy are equally evil!")
}
```

The `if` line gives an error: `Type 'AnyObject?' does not conform to protocol '_RawOptionSetType'`.

**How am I supposed to compare these values?**

According to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/userData), SKNode.userData is `NSMutableDictionary?`. Since it is optional, I am sure to unwrap the values using `!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userData` is an NSMutableDictionary. This worked for me:

```
if hero.userData!.objectForKey("isEvil") as Bool == enemy.userData!.objectForKey("isEvil") as Bool
```

EDIT: As pointed out by @DonnyP, it can be written even simpler:

```
if hero.userData!["isEvil"] as Bool == enemy.userData!["isEvil"] as Bool
```

Comment: Any idea what the difference is between `userData!.objectForKey("isEvil"`) and just `userData!["isEvil"]`? I'm not aware of one

Comment: Me neither. There might be a difference, or it might just be syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...it will handle if `isEvil` is not defined, if `userData` is `nil`, and/or if `isEvil` is not a `Bool`:

```
    if hero.userData?["isEvil"] as? Bool == enemy.userData?["isEvil"] as? Bool {
        println("the hero and the enemy are equally evil!")
    }
```